# What are best practices for backing up settings files?

Tags: 8, version-control

I have a Drupal 8 multisite with a few different hosts for production, staging, and local dev. Certain important files like settings.php and .htaccess are excluded from git, making it complicated to push to staging and production from my local.

How are people getting around this? Is putting them in .git such a big security risk?

For some time, I've been excluding .htaccess from .git and creating a .htaccess-loca, .htaccess-prod, etc., putting them in .git and copying them to the .htaccess files on the difference hosts - but these also contain the same info. Not sure why these are a security issue. The .env files I can understand. The problem with settings.php is the contain database passwords; can I move them to .env and consider settings files safe for git? Can Drupal console be used for synchronizing these files? I'd rather not use sftp, and like git so I can roll back to known stable versions.

I used composer to build the site, can Composer be used to manage settings, env, and other config files?

How about Docsall, would that make things easier?

Comment: I always commit settings.php and then have it include an ignored settings.local.php which holds all environment-specific and sensitive information. Of course the settings.local.php file must then be managed manually somehow, like an .env file. I see no problem with the .htaccess file.